# What items are useless on Lilith?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth

Last time I was playing greed mode with Lilith I came upon Blood Clot pickup which normally causes a character to shoot one normal tear and one damage-enhanced alternately.

I know that in case of Cain for example (as he doesn't have one eye/wears an eyepatch) this is changed to randomly shoot red and normal tears without alteration, but Lilith's default familiar only shot normal tears, and damage was not increased anyhow as per Missing HUD2 addon statistics, hence rendering this item useless.

I want to limit out buying items that won't affect Lilith, even though they could somehow (as it is with Cain).

So the question is:
**TL;DR:** What items do not affect Lilith in any way, even though they could (literally thinking)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These items will have different or no effect:

- **Cursed Eye**: No effect.
- **Dead Eye**: Incubus tears still receive the damage boost. Has no effect on Lilith as she has no normal tears.
- **Epic Fetus**: Incubus still shoots normal tears.
- **Loki's Horns**: No effect.
- **Maw Of The Void**: Damage increased. Incubus will not trigger the Brimstone ring.
- **Mom's Knife**: Incubus gains a smaller knife with much shorter range and quicker charge time.
- **Tech.5**: No effect.
- **Technology 2**: No laser, tear damage decreased.
- **The Ludovico Technique**: Incubus' tears become piercing and spectral.
- **Isaac's Tears**: Lilith can only use it once as she has no normal tears to recharge it.

**EDIT**:

After the last update **Isaac's Tears** seems to be fixed, *Incubus* now recharges it too.

---

For reference, [Rebirth wikia](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Incubus).

Comment: I'd add Isaac Tears to the list, since it can be used only once (it recharges with Isaac's shooting, so, being Lilith blindfolded, it never recharges)

Comment: @pinckerman Isaac's Tears seems to be fixed for Lilith - she now properly charges it with Succubus shots.

Comment: @Asunez Ok, I haven't tried it yet, but I'll update my answer.

Comment: @pinckerman I messed up with the items - it's the Incubus that charges the Isaac's Tears (Lilith's starting item). Sorry for the mess!

Comment: @Asunez Fixed, they have a similar name :)

Comment: You might want to note this - Tech 2 with Lilith's Incubus will not add a laser, but still decrease tear damage.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use epic fetus as Lilith. But her familiar shoots normal tears and Lilith shoots the strike